# Implementing embedded NoSQL: low-level approaches to data storage

Tags: nosql, storage

I trying to build a lightweight embedded nosql database in .NET (more just to learn things than for actual production use). The idea is to store a record (serialized, a set of bytes) and be able to get it in by identifier and get list of records based on sorting criteria. The records can be updated and deleted quite often. The database should be crash safe.

How you would approach the storage (basically, the data file structure, let's ignore indexes if this complicates the question)? Are there good articles on this matter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found these:

- [Berkeley DB (pdf)](http://www.usenix.org/event/usenix99/full_papers/olson/olson.pdf)
- [B+ tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B+_tree)

B+ tree seems to be what I need.
Existing implementation for .NET: http://csharptest.net/projects/bplustree/.